# How to check if job has been finished?

Tags: java, json

I have json response which has three different status "processing", "pending", "finished". I want to set a timer which checks this **json** status if it has finished. For that I have the following code:

```
       json = jsonDataWrapper.wrap(jobCreateResponse, JobResponseJSON.class);

    final Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule( new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            if(json.getStatus().equals("Finished"))
                timer.cancel();

        }
    }, 5, 60*1000);
```

This scheduler doesn't wait till the timer finishes its task which has been mentioned. Is there any way to check the status of **json** to check after certain time if it has been finished, with status "Finished" ?

Comment: What do you mean "this scheduler doesn't wait till the timer finishes its task"?

Comment: It seems that you never update `json` object after timer started. From your code leads that you do not understand multithreading pricinple